# How can I make parent <button> take size of child <svg>

Tags: html, css

I use svg image with help of `use` from previously created sprite. The problem is that when I have `<svg>` inside of `button` then div takes the whole space available when expected income is to be the same size as child. 
Any help?

My code:

```html
<button class="presentation__video-controls-play-pause" id="play-pause">
    <svg class="play-pause-icon" width="22" height="29" viewBox="0 0 22 29">
        <use href="img/icons/sprite.svg#play"></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to make padding and margin of parent 0

```html
<button class="presentation__video-controls-play-pause" id="play-pause" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
    <svg class="play-pause-icon" width="22" height="29" viewBox="0 0 22 29">
        <use href="img/icons/sprite.svg#play"></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: I've found I often have to also set line-height to 0.